# Polynomial dividing a power of another polynomial

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $f \in \mathbb{F}_{q}[x]$, and let $x^n - 1$ divide $f^{k}$ in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$, for some natural number $k$.

If $gcd(n,q) = 1$, then apparently I can deduce that $x^n - 1$ divides $f$?

How is this true? Apparently it is enough to check that the polynomial $x^n - 1$ is square-free, which is easy to see, but I don't understand how this shows that $x^n - 1$ divides $f$?

Answer (score 3):

Assume $n$ and $q$ are coprime. Then $x^n-1$ is coprime with its derivative, thus is the product of its irreducible factors.

If $p$ is an irreducible factor of $x^n-1$, then $p|f^k$. Thus $p$ must divide $f$.

Then the product of the irreducible factors of $x^n-1$, which is $x^n-1$, divides $f$.

Comment: Why does $p$ dividing $f^k$ imply that $p$ divides $f$?

Comment: Because $p$ is irreducible. Same mechanism saying that if $n^2$ is even, then $n$ is even.

Comment: @theman In a UFD irred's $p$ are prime i,e, if $p$ divides a product then it divides some factor, so $\,p\mid f^n\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid f.\ $ Here $\,x^n-1\,$ is *squarefree*, i.e. a product of *nonassociate* primes.